# How to avoid use a WCF service from unknown client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm developing a windows forms application that use a WCF service developed by me hosted on internet paying hosting.

On my WCF service i have some OperationContracts to provide some funcionallity to Windows forms client.
If i set a new service reference pointing to my WCF service in my Windows forms client i can use that OperationContracts. No problems up to here.

If someone 'knows' the address to my WCF service, anyone can use my 'own' WCF service in his/her 'own' client application.

Using a tool like a Wireshark its really simple to retrieve the WCF service url.

So, my question...There is some kind of protection for avoiding that?
I don't want that 'other clients' to use my own WCF service.

PS: can not use SSL certificates on my paying hosting.

Comment: Adding reference is not a big problem..But you can put the **authentication** so that only valid client can access the features (operation contract).

Comment: Do you really want to make it so that only your CLIENT can access the service, or are you really concerned about making sure only authorised USERS can, regardless of what client they are using. It is impossible to ensure 100% that only your client can call your service. On the other hand  it is easy to ensure that only authorised users can.

Comment: Reading this msdn link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx) i see that there are some authentications methods (Windows, Basic, Certificate, NTLM or none) I can not use anyone of these. Windows obiously not. My app isnt a Domain app, Basic neither (open it with some 'reflector' and get the user/pass in nanoseconds), NTLM neither (like windows auth), and finally Certificate maybe, but i don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, and even if it is I'd recommend implementing some kind of authorization as well, but you can disable the WSDL for the service by setting the `httpGetEnabled` attribute to false in the service's config file:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This will disable publishing of the WSDL (at least as I understand it).  So add the service reference to your application, and then set the value to "false".  Even if someone sniffs your service address, they won't be able to pull the WSDL to generate a proxy.

**EDIT**

To clarify, setting the attribute above to false does not hide the service URL - it simply disables the WSDL.  Anybody who knows your service URL but does **NOT** have a proxy would need the WSDL to generate the proxy.  `httpGetEnabled="false"` prevents the WSDL from being served, thereby preventing generation of a proxy.

Since you cannot use an SSL certificate on your hosting site, a custom user name validator (even using message as the transport mode) appears to not be an option, because WCF "WCF enforces that the transport is secured when using UserName credentials." (see [`<message>` element of `<wsHttpBinding>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731309%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example), about the only other option I can see for you would be to use a Security Token Service (STS).

A final option would be to put the service on a private network, but that might defeat what you're trying to accomplish, depending on your requirements.

Another final option (which makes it not a final option, I guess) would be to move to a hosting site that *does* allow you to use SSL.

For an STS, you can take a look at [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151.aspx), which is fully integrated with .NET 4.5.  If you're using an earlier version of .NET, you can look at [WCF Security Token Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748498.aspx).

Comment: Security by obscurity often bites.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - I agree, which is why I also recommended using some sort of authorization as well.

Comment: @Tim i disabled de WSDL for the service by setting the httpGetEnabled to false and this is what i get using Wireshark sniffer: http://i.imgur.com/l6TVC5g.png. Blue rectangle: The name of my WCF service, for example /testing.svc Cyan rectangle: The main Url, for example: http://www.someting.com...so..anyone can put a Web reference in her/his own client pointing to http://www.something.com/testing.svc

Comment: @user3122306 - I think you misunderstood what I was saying.  Re-read the last sentence of my answer: "Even if someone sniffs your service address, they **won't be able to pull the WSDL to generate a proxy."**  Being able to hit the service address is **not** the same thing as being able to **use** the service.

Comment: If someone can sniff dataexchange with server, he can write proxy to use service without WSDL. Of cause not every one will do this, but hacker can do this and it will cost.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov - Sure, that could happen.  If someone wants to get into something bad enough, given enough time and the right tools they will eventually succeed.  The point in my answer was that disabling the metadata to prevent publishing the WSDL would go a long ways to deterring the casual attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You should add authentication to your service. Authentication could be on different technologies:
username-password, certificates, and so on.
About simplest username-password auth you can read [here](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/).

Comment: The article you've linked still requires a certificate - "For username password authentication to work your server hosting the service needs an X509 certificate"

Comment: If you will use https it is not.

Comment: ... But you have to have a cert to use https!

Comment: and what do you want me to say? This certificate used for transport security, not for authentication.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but the original question says that the OP can't use SSL certs on their hosting...

Comment: You understand fine. Of course someone needs a certificate to use https. A cheeper choice would be to use a self-signed certificate, which the developer would not have to buy. If the developer ensists on not using https, he actually cannot have encryption and therefore cannot have authentication in a sensible manner...